# Discrete Math - Given n>= 5, how many times does fib(4) occur?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computer-science, fibonacci-numbers

I have been trying to solve the problem below (and similar problems) but I have no clue how to tackle it. Can you please help me tackle this particular problem, and how to attack similar problems?

The question in question is question 11 at this link: http://cglab.ca/~michiel/2804/winter14exam.pdf

That was an old exam that I was trying to work through. I know he will ask a similar type of question so I would like to be prepared. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Since this is a multiple choice test, the best way to solve the *exam* question is to actually run through the computation for $n=5$. Since all of the answers are distinct for $n=5$, this will uniquely specify the answer.

As for actually solving the *mathematical* question, you might notice that FIB$(4)$ is called exactly once whenever FIB$(5)$ is called and exactly one more time whenever FIB$(6)$ is called. You can generalize this observation and try to find a recurrence relation for the $a_n$.

Comment: can you explain it a bit further?

Comment: @user199115: I'd rather not, no. Do the computation of $a_n$ for $n=5$ and $n=6$ and $n=7$ and take a guess at the general form. Then back-justify it (or prove it) by arguing for a recurrence relation.

Comment: k, that actually helped more. Thanks

Comment: @user199115: Glad it helped. You should not be afraid to do things like this, although in the time pressure of an exam it might be better to skip it and come back later